# Physics simulations (upward collision)

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I would like to carry out a physics simulation in my project: context, I have a cooler (ice cream freezer) and inside it is full of ice cubes, the issue is that I want ice cream to come out of the cooler and when you get up (animate +Z) the Ice cream, lift the ice too, like collision, but I haven't been able to do it, could someone please help me? thnx a lot guys.

[image]

Comment: hello do you an image of what you've already done, or a storyboard?

Comment: yes bro,  https://i.imgur.com/jn0ypUa.jpg